# How to write a dataframe column with json data (STRING type) to BigQuery table as JSON type using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, spark-bigquery-connector

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column containing json string (column type is string). I would like to write this dataframe to Bigquery table with column type as JSON. I got below information from this link
https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector

*Spark has no JSON type. The values are read as String. In order to write JSON back to BigQuery, the following conditions are REQUIRED:*

- *Use the INDIRECT write method*
- *Use the AVRO intermediate format*
- *The DataFrame field MUST be of type String and has an entry of sqlType=JSON in its metadata*

I am not sure how to set an entry of sqlType=JSON in dataframe field metadata? Can someone please help?

I am using below code to write dataframe to Bigquery table

```
df.write \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket","some-bucket") \
  .save("dataset.table")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have look at the withMetadata column.

[pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withMetadata](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withMetadata.html)

```
df_meta = df.withMetadata('age', {'foo': 'bar'})
df_meta.schema['age'].metadata
{'foo': 'bar'}
```